# Rotate glutBitmapString around its center

Tags: java, string, glut, jogl

Does anyone know if you can rotate the text around the middle (verical axis). with me he always turns around his left side.

Comment: Do you use glutBitmapString or glutStrokeString? You should use the latter, just compare their respective documentations: https://linux.die.net/man/3/glutbitmapstring https://linux.die.net/man/3/glutstrokestring

Comment: This shows the same effect. Its rotating around its origin not its center.